# Yii2: joinWith andFilterWhere with find_in_set

Tags: mysql, yii2, yii2-model

I am trying to convert an SQL query like this

```
select 
t1.id,t1.form,t1.type,
group_concat(t2.department) as departments
from appraisal t1 
join department t2 on find_in_set(t2.id,t1.dept) 
group by t1.id
```

into yii2 AppraisalSearch model.

I tried

```
$query->joinWith(['departments' ,  'on find_in_set(department.id,appraisal.dept)   ']);
```

and

```
$query->andFilterWhere(
                 ['group_concat','appraisal','departments.department'])
```

, but it does not give correct results.

I also have added relation in appraisal model like

```
public function getDepartments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Department::className(), ['id' => 'dept']);
    }
```

What is the correct format to make this query work?

The table structure for appraisal table is

```
--
-- Table structure for table `appraisal`
--

CREATE TABLE `appraisal` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `form` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_time` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_time` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dept` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin_id` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `appr` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `apps` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `desg_appr` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `desg_apps` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remark` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sem` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `acad_yr` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `appraisal`
--
ALTER TABLE `appraisal`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

and table structure for department is

```
--
-- Table structure for table `department`
--

CREATE TABLE `department` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `department` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `department`
--
ALTER TABLE `department`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

In appraisal table, appraisal.dept , the values are stored in comma separated form, like `1,2,33,4` . Also how to apply `andFilterWhere` conditions for `departments` field

Comment: 1. What does `not working` mean? Do you get an exception? If yes, pls share the exception with us. Do you get unexpected results? Then pls describe the results. 2. The SQL query has a group by clause, but no where clause. The yii code seems to do this the other way around.

Comment: Both `joinWith` and `andFilterWhere` are not implemented correctly.  Also, you're using `andFilterWhere` (which adds conditions to the `WHERE` clause) in order to insert your `group_concat` expression, which clearly needs to go in the `SELECT` clause.  I recommend you refamiliarize yourself with Yii2's documentation, and then try to come at this problem again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be careful while using aliases they should not be any of the  [**`MySQL reserved keywords`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-7-detailed-V). So it is better not to use `value` but any other like `myVal` or more descriptive name that defines the value in it. I will use `myVal` in the example below.

You should use the following way to transform the query into the search model but before you add it you should declare a custom field named `$myVal` on top of your search model and rather than using the `andFilterWhere` for the related model you should specify it within `joinWith()` function using the relation `departments` when selecting the related model or `leftJoin` with the table `department` using `FIND_IN_SET`.

Define a custom field

`public $myVal;`

Then add the following inside your search model.

```
public function search(){
        $query=Appraisel::find();
        $query->select(new \yii\db\Expression('[[id]],group_concat(d.[[department]]) as myVal'));
        $query->leftJoin('{{%department}} d', 'find_in_set(d.[[id]],{{%appraisal}}.[[dept]])');

         $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
             'pagination'=>[
                 'pageSize'=>20
             ]
        ]);

        $query->groupBy(['{{%appraisal}}.[[id]]']);
        return $dataProvider;
}
```

Hoipe it helps you out.

Comment: It did not work as intended. in t1.dept. values are stored as comma separated like 1,22,3 .

Comment: you said you have the relation defined `departments`? anyhow I have changed the code check if this helps you out and do one thing if it does not work, add the `echo $query->createCommand()->rawSql;` in the end and comment out the `return  $dataProvider`. and paste the SQL that is generated. @user7282